# building a boosting model for repeated measurments

Tags: machine-learning, regression, boosting

I am working on an e-commerce data where the goal is to predict how will the user rate a movie from 1 to 5. We have a bunch of data from users but also from products. Some users have previously rated more than 10 (even 100s) and some less. Something like the following.

[image]

Imaging I am using a boosting model **xgboost/catboost/lightgbm/...** - I can feed the model with the data (excel the user_id) column and get sth that can predict the rate. but I believe this model is not at the personal level - meaning is not tailored to learn what each user like and is rather a generic model. So ideally there would be a tree per user.

I wonder how I can make this model to work at the personal level ? for example, learn that user_id 12 likes `x` and `y` but not `z` and `w` ?

How can I inform that model to build tree at each user ? I am sorry if I am not using the right terminology or the best title.